# EditorTemplate not overriding my textbox in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I can't get my DateTime EditorTemplate to work.

I have in my ViewModel:

```
 public class CreateViewModel
{
    // Customer
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Arrival Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [UIHint("DateTime")]
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
}
```

I also have in my Shared -> EditorTemplates folder, DateTime.cshtml:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox(
"", 
string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Model ?? DateTime.Today), 
new { 
    @class = "textbox datepicker"
} 
)
```

On my view I have:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ArrivalDate)
```

However, my DateTime.cshtml doesn't appear to be called - as it's still showing the date in the textbox as:

`15/07/2013 00:00:00` but it should be `15 July 2013` - with NO time.

What is it I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using Html.TextBox or Html.Display?

Comment: Hi - I'm using:  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ArrivalDate)

Comment: Aha - I see now, if you used EditorFor it works!!!

Comment: Please, mark this as correct answer. This can help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wand to use and Editor Template, you need to use `Html.Editor` or `Html.EditorFor`

If you use any other helper, like `Html.TextBox` or `Html.TextboxFor`, the template won't be applied.

Similarly, if you want to use a Display Template, you need to use `Html.Display` or `Html.DisplayFor`.